# jquery plugin authoring inside method calling from another inside method

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins, each

I'm new with jquery plugin authoring and wonder how a method in the plugin can call another method inside the same plugin.

In the sample code I'm trying to call f2 from f1 but I have a js error because of this.each() in the f2 method.

Can you enlighten me ?

Thanks

Edit : f1() and f2() can be called from outside the plugin $.pluginName('f1') and $.pluginName('f2').

What I want is to call f2() after somme code in f1().

```
;
(function( $ ){
    'use strict';

    var pluginName = 'pluginName';

    var defaults = {
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) {
            return this.each(function ( ) {
                var $this = $(this);
                var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                $this.data(pluginName, settings);
                return $this;
            });
        },

        f1 : function() {
            methods.f2(); // Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'each' 
        },

        f2 : function() {
            return this.each(function() {

            });
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.' + pluginName + '()');
        }
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is showing error because when you call `f2()` from `f1()` You are not passing the jQuery objects to `f2()` so `this` wont refer to the same object inside `f2()` and hence it wont work.

So change your `f1()` code like this

```
f1 : function() {
            // some code of F1
            this.css('color','red');
            // now call f2
            methods.f2.apply(this,[]); 
        },
```

It's specifying what `this` will mean inside `f2()`. And in this case we are passing the jQuery object.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yNHFQ/)

More on [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)